# Always render the visible objects

Tags: rendering, objects

I am using Blender for some scientific-related visualization. As such I guess my needs are much more modest than those of the average animator, and the decoupling of the visibility and renderability of objects (i.e., the fact I can set some object to rendered although it is not visible in preview) only causes problems for me, when I change what is visible but forget to also set it to be rendered, only to come back 15 minutes later and see that I had rendered the wrong scene. Is there some way to "couple" visibility and renderability, i.e. only whatever is set as visible is also set as renderable?

Answer (score 4):

You could also do this with Python!

To do so you could run the following  code, manually, before rendering:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.hide_render = obj.hide
```

A better solution would be to somehow run the code automagically before rendering, which can be  done as follows:

```
import bpy

def unhide(self):
     for obj in bpy.data.objects:
          obj.hide_render = obj.hide

bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(unhide)
```

To make the script run every time you open up the blend file, name your text block with a `.py` extension and check `Register`.

Note that you must run the script once;

Comment: I tried so hard to do this... D:

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I noticed in chat :)  it really is simple, though

Comment: I kept on trying to do it using the same steps as my answer :/. I don't really no how to code python, or anything about whats in bpy....

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Python is really simple; and as far as knowing the API,  there's always the api docs and Google it self :D

Comment: @someonewithpc - give the textblock a `.py` name and enable register - it will run on file open.

Comment: @someonewithpc New question on this?

Comment: @poor On how to making a script run when a file is opened? Sure

Comment: @someonewithpc nice! You are too fast :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple process to do before rendering:

1. Deselect all your object <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide all the objects
3. Without changing the selection, hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>, your objects will be hidden
4. Hit <kbd>H</kbd> to hide them again.

Answer (score 2):

For better scene organization I suggest you to use the new layer management addon. With this you can simply disable a layer if you don't want to render it.

[image]