# How to run a script before rendering

Tags: python, rendering

After answering the question [Always render the visible objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23139/always-render-the-visible-objects) I realized that,  rather than running the script manually, it would be easier to have it run automagically, *once*, before rendering (that includes the `building BVH` phase),  however,  I couldn't find a way to do this.  How would that be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do this be adding a function to:

`bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(function_name)`

This way whatever function you name will be called before the render happens. Here is a little info on it: [link](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.render_pre)

Make sure your function takes `self` as a parameter, like so:

`function_name(self):
    print("Test")`

Comment: You need to have **def unhide(self):**, then it works.