# Can i Render a specific region in blender with specific resolution?

Tags: rendering, resolution

For example, can I define a *Render Region*, but render it at the resolution I've specified in *Output Properties*?

[image: where region = resolution]

Comment: It's kind of difficult for us to understand what you're asking here.  Do you think you could explain in a little more detail please?

Comment: Yes let's say I have an image in resolution 7,680 by 4,320px and I want to render just a section of it but that section to be again  7,680 by 4,320px.

Comment: I've edited the body of your question to match, please revert it if I've made a mistake

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use another camera.

1. Duplicate your camera, and keep it in the same place
2. Lower the *Sensor size* to "crop" the image
3. Use *Shift X* and *Y* to "move around"

Because you're not changing focal length, the lens distortion doesn't change.
It's as if you cropped the image in photoshop.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Python script that calculates and changes resolution accordingly, renders, and restores old resolution.

### A simplified version

Most people will actually want this: you don't have to specify the output resolution with the same aspect ratio as the region's dimensions to avoid stretching - the script makes sure your image has at least as many pixels as you specified for both dimensions. If one of the dimensions is too big, it will have accordingly more pixels in order to keep aspect ratio:

```
import bpy

render = bpy.context.scene.render

width_original = render.resolution_x
height_original = render.resolution_y

horizontal_ratio = render.border_max_x - render.border_min_x
vertical_ratio = render.border_max_y - render.border_min_y

# to keep aspect ratio:
# simply take the axis which is more empty and so has to be scaled more
# the other axis will end up having more resolution, than specified

ratio = min(horizontal_ratio, vertical_ratio)

render.resolution_x = round(width_original / ratio)
render.resolution_y = round(height_original / ratio)

bpy.ops.render.render()

render.resolution_x = width_original 
render.resolution_y = height_original
```

### A correct version

This produces the exact region, as visible in the viewport, in the exact resolution specified in the output settings. It's equivalent to using the first version and then scaling it in 2D software to target resolution with *"Keep aspect ratio"* disabled.

```
import bpy

render = bpy.context.scene.render

width_original = render.resolution_x
height_original = render.resolution_y

asp_x = render.pixel_aspect_x
asp_y = render.pixel_aspect_y

horizontal_ratio =  render.border_max_x - render.border_min_x
vertical_ratio =  render.border_max_y - render.border_min_y

render.resolution_x = round(width_original / horizontal_ratio)
render.resolution_y = round(height_original / vertical_ratio)

if horizontal_ratio < vertical_ratio:
    render.pixel_aspect_y *= vertical_ratio / horizontal_ratio
else:
    render.pixel_aspect_x *= horizontal_ratio / vertical_ratio

bpy.ops.render.render()

render.resolution_x = width_original 
render.resolution_y = height_original
render.pixel_aspect_x = asp_x
render.pixel_aspect_y = asp_y
```

**You can use pre/post render handlers to apply/restore those settings automatically for each render:**

[How to run a script before rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23167/how-to-run-a-script-before-rendering/23168)