# How do i remove the box in the middle of my character

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting

I was modeling a body for practice and i decided to render it to see how it would look like and this came out:

[image: Render]

And this is how the mesh looks like in the viewport:

[image: Viewport]

What's the cause for the strange box in the middle of my object and how to remove it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Make sure that there aren't any hidden objects; this one looks like part of original mesh duplicated, separated and now casting shadow on the body mesh. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23139/always-render-the-visible-objects

Comment: Try Remove Doubles - could be that you have additional geometry that is affecting the resulting mesh.